# always 1st item get deleted when ever i tap on the delete button not the particular item which i want to delete

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
app.get('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
 var id = req.query.id;
 console.log(id);
 MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {
   if(err) { throw err;  }

   db.collection('shopping_list', function(err, products) {
     products.deleteOne({_id: mongodb.ObjectID(id)});
     if (err){
        throw err;
      }else{
         //console.log("deleted");
         
         db.close();
      }
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<body>
    
    <h1> Shopping List </h1>
    <img src="images/cart.png" id="cart">

    <div class="text">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Find" id="find"/>
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><input type="submit" id="find" value="Search" style="background-color: #a3a3c2 ;color:white; width:170px;"></a>
    </div>
    <form action="/add" method="POST">
    <div class="f">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/fc.jpg" class="follow"></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twt.jpg"  class="follow"></a>
        <a href="http://www.instgram.com"><img src="images/ins1.jpg" class="follow"></a>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="container">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label style="margin-left: 20px;">Shopping item</label>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                <label>Quantity</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" id="item" name="item"/>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                <input type="text" id="quan" name="quan"/>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add item" style="background-color: #a3a3c2 ; color:white; width:170px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>

   </form>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="tbody">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                </table>
            </div>
            
                
        </div>
    </div>
     
    <button id="btn" style="background-color: #a3a3c2 ; color:white; width:170px; margin-left:807px; margin-top:30px;">Clear</button>
    
    

    <script>
    $(function() {
   // GET
   
       $.ajax({
           url: '/render',
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
   
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   

                   var trHTML = '';
                   trHTML += '<tr>';
                   trHTML += '<td style="display:none" id="id">' +data[i]._id +'</td>';
                   trHTML += '<td >' + data[i].item + '</td>';
                   trHTML += '<td >' + data[i].quantity + '</td>';
                   trHTML += '<td >' + '<button class="delete-button" style="background-color: #a3a3c2 ; color:white; width:170px; margin-left:370px;">Delete</button>' + '</td>';
                 
                   trHTML += '</tr>';
                   $('#tbody').append(trHTML);
               }
           }
           });
       

      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('table').on('click', '.delete-button', function() {

       alert("Confirm delete");
       var id=$('#id').html();
       console.log(id);
       //var rowEl = $(this).closest('tr');
       //var id = rowEl.find('.id').text();*/
       $.ajax({
           url: '/delete',
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'json',
           data:{id:id},
           success: function(data) {
               alert("deleted");
           
           //$(this).closest('tr').remove();
       }
   });
   });
  });
```

always 1st item get deleted when ever i tap on the delete button not the particular item which i want to delete

every time item which is on the top of the database get deleted when i use the delete button but i want particular item to be delete.
as i provide individual delete button for each item also im facing the same problem.

Comment: What is the console output when you press the Delete button?

Comment: id of first item in the database

Comment: Does your ID in this table equals the ID in your database ?

Comment: yes both are same

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
var id=$('#id').html();
```

Because you have multiple cells with the ID of 'id', this assignment picks the first one. Change it to this:

```
var id = $(this).parent().siblings('#id').text();
```

to get the contents of the 'id' cell on the same row as your delete button.

Comment: Edited, try now

Comment: Cool! If you can accept the answer then people who wander here in the future will know that this solution works, and maybe it will help them, too.